# Does Careers 2.0 consider other StackExchange accounts to open a profile?

Tags: support, jobs, stack-exchange

Just curious as if Careers 2.0 checks information about other StackExchange accounts to evaluate if someone can open a profile or not. I wouldn't think that the Chess site would count, but other sites like Programmers seem related and usable to me.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't say with authority, but I would imagine that they would accept most of the technical sites - Unix, SU, SF, possibly AU. Not sure about Prog.SE, that primarily covers more logistical topics, not so much direct programming.